# Error 1053: Service did not respond in time

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core

I created a new Windows-Service project and added it to the services using sc.exe, but I am always getting the error when I try to execute the Service.

Code in Program:

```
static void Main() {
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new Service1()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Code in ServiceBase:

```
public Service1() {
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    while(true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Message all 5 sec...");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}

protected override void OnStop() {
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

I tried extending the Timeout in Registry(ServicesPipeTimeout), Using Threads and owning the Service but i still get the error.

Any Help is appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service will never get out of the onStart-callback because of the endless loop you have created there. So this is blocking and will never finish.

You need to use a timer for your use-case. Just start a timer in your OnStart method and it shall run as expected:

```
public Service1() {
    InitializeComponent();
}

public OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
    timer.Start();
}
public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message all 5 sec...");
}
```

The timer will send an event every 5 seconds and the added ElapsedEventHandler will call your OnTimer-Method.